Do I need an article?
In a sentence: "... in the play "Wooden House"."
Do I need to place "the" before "Wooden House"(Play name). I feel like I don't because "play" has it already. Also, the sentence itself is a part of a diploma.

Can you link to play script?  or to an listing of it's performance.  I don't know what you mean by "part of a diploma" or how that is relevant.

You should use the actual name of of the play.

In the play The Tempest  ....


In the play Twelfth Night ...

Because the name of the first play includes the word "The", but the name of the second does not.
There is some flexibility in this, and sometimes an article in a proper noun is dropped.  So you might sometimes see "I'm performing in Shakespeare's Tempest at the Globe".
Since we don't know the actual name of your play (it is not a very famous play) we don't know if the author used "The" or not.
I you are translating from a language that doesn't use articles, then I'd suggest including "the".  Most plays titles do.  For example Вишнёвый сад is translated as The Cherry Orchard.

And notice that @JamesK has set the titles not in quotation marks but in italics. FYI, that is the convention in English.
